# FlashBuilder edit Class of Symbol defined in Flash IDE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, swc

When coding in the Flash IDE, i very often use the following procedure to create specialized versions of MovieClip classes:

I design my object in the IDE, for example, i add two buttons and give them the instance names "btn1" and "btn2". Then i select them together and convert them to a symbol. I then select Export for ActionScript and give them a classname, let's say "MyClass".

Then I go and write a specialized MyClass.as for it, like this:

```
public class MyClass extends MovieClip{
    private var _button1:Button;
    private var _button2:Button;

    public function MyClass(){
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        ....
    }

    private function init(e:Event){
        _button1 = this["btn1"];
        _button2 = this["btn2"];
    }

    ...
}
```

(ps: i know that i wouldn't have to assign the values to the private variables _button1 and _button2 and instead could directly make calls to btn1, but I like to use only Typesafe variables in my code)

This works very well in Flash IDE. when I create a new instance of MyClass() it will contain all the elements that i positioned in the Flash IDE when defining the Symbol. This is very convenient and straight forward.

Now I want to do the same in FlashBuilder.

For this i designed the MyClass Symbol as before in Flash IDE, gave it the classname MyClass and then select the library symbol and export it to MyClass.SWC

In Flash Builder i add MyClass.SWC to the buildpath and I write a MyClass.as with the same code as in the Flash IDE example. but this time, the code won't work. on

```
_button1 = this["btn1"];
```

i will get an Error #1069 stating that "btn1" was not defined.

So - how to do this properly if developing with Flash Builder?

PS: i use the default package in Flash IDE when setting the Classname for the symbol as well as in FlashBuilder for the as file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest that now you are moving to Flash Builder that you change your approach slightly. Although there is nothing wrong with using a swc, your assets are embedded at compile time, which means you need to recompile your app if you change them.

I have been using an approach of putting movieclips in a swf and loading it in, and then to keep the type safety that you describe I use the IMediaLibrary approach. See the following article:

[Runtime Class Extraction](http://lassieadventurestudio.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/runtime-class-extraction/)

Doing it this way means you can also share this swf with other applications, it may contain icons or whatever you want, but I think you will find the approach very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a swc (but you can). There is a way to have flash Builder and flash IDE nicely interwoven for a project, but you have to set it up correctly.
In flash IDE - go to edit->Prefrences Then choose actionscript. Click actionscript 3 settings and put the source path to the folder containing all the .as files you need. 
Then in flash builder go to project -> properties Click actionscript build path and go to the tab for Source Path. Here choose the same folder that you chose in ide (my folder is named lib) Now back in IDE set your document class relative to the folder you chose. So if you chose lib, and inside of lib are the folders com, inside that phone, and inside that MainClass.as then in the IDE base class you would enter com.phone.MainClass
Now when you change flash builder code and compile in flash IDE it should work for you :)

Also, here is an easier (clearer, maybe) way to access items in your library

```
_phoneItselfClass = getDefinitionByName("PhoneItself") as Class;
_phoneItself:Sprite = new _phoneItselfClass() as Sprite;
```

This could be like your "main panel". Then all buttons could be accessed like this:

_phoneItself["btn1"].addEventListener....
_phoneItself["btn2"].visible = true;

Cheers,
Jim